# Unable to Exit (System Freeze) when remotely logged in SSH

Tags: ssh, remote-debugging, exit

Newbie to this forum...
I was working on something lately and encountered a problem. First i logged on to a remote system using "ssh -l hostname" then i killed all processes with pid = trace using "killall -9 trace", then after performing some work i tried to reinvoke this process in the background using '&' and typed "exit" but system hangs. I understood SSH wasnt able to detach from the running process so it wasnt able to exit (it was a deadlock) is there anyway to over come this situation!?

PS: I am using Busy box ie cannot use nohup or anyother special functions... help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup), which allows a background job to keep running even though the controlling terminal (your login session) has gone away.

Comment: I am having problem with that.. I am not using regular linux terminal, i am logging in to a remote server that has a terminal called busybox v1.00. that is where i encounter this problem